# Will my app be able to run on newer iOS if from old Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I starting creating an app in Xcode 8.3, which only tests in iOS up to 10 and does not let me use my phone to test because it has iOS 12. Will I be able to upload this to the App Store, and will it be able to run on newer devices? If not, can I open my project from Xcode 8 in a newer version, like Xcode 10?

Comment: You will need to upgrade to Xcode 10.2 in order to submit to the App Store since apps must be built against the iOS 12 SDK from March this year. Xcode 10 will open your old project but you will probably need to upgrade your swift code to swift 4 so there will be some work required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Starting March 27, 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later"
https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

It means only Xcode 10.2

Comment: Thanks! What is the best way to move my project to a new computer? I was running xcode in a macOS Sierra VirtualBox and am now downloading xcode 10.2 in macOS Mojave VirtualBox. I will need to move the project to the new VirtualBox. Should I use google drive, a flash drive, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to migarate your project to **swift 4.0 or above**. This can be easily done via **XCode 10.2** but if your app was build on swift 3.0 or below, you may need to use XCode 10.1 or 10.0